# ASP.NET Web API 2 MediaTypeFormatter XML no result

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api2

checking some documentation about `Serialization`, I got the impression that if `DataContractSerializer` is used, there is no particular setup to serialize in a similar way json and xml.

Now, I have a problem which seems opposite to the common one, I am not able to get anything back in xml format. 
With the snippet as below, where d is the data I want to send back

```
System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter formatter;
if (contentType.FirstOrDefault() == "text/xml" || contentType.FirstOrDefault() == "application/xml")
{
    formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
    (formatter as System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter).Indent = true;

}
else if (contentType.FirstOrDefault() == "text/html")
{
    formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
}
else
{
        formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        (formatter as System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter).SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        (formatter as System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter).SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
}

httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, d, formatter);
```

---

Where `d` is defined as

```
public class FeatureModel : ModelBase
    {
        public List<Feature> Data { get; set; }

        public class Feature : Common.ClassBase
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            public int feature_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am able to receive back data in json format while reply is empty

[image]